# How to fix this strftime() error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to only print `'%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M'`, but
when I say:

```
print(loan_due.strftime('%d/%m/%Y, %H:%M'))
```

I'm getting an error saying `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'`.

I tried many ways but it's still not working for me. `loan_due` I have in my json file and this how it looks:

```
{"customer": [{"loan_due": "22/12/2017, 19:02:39:4536"}]}
```

Comment: `my_dict['customer'][0]['loan_due']` is just a string. You need it to be a `datetime` object to be able to call `stftime` on it. Look into `strptime` to convert a string to a datetime. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: You would also need to `import datetime` for that to work. You haven't provided a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert it to a string, because it's actually already a string. If you want to change the way in which the string is formatted, try converting it to a datetime object first.

The easiest way to do this is using datetime.strptime. You can review the documentation for it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

You can then use your datetime.strftime to convert this to whatever format you see fit.